# Scrolling with two ListViews, trying to populate a LinearLayout instead

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

got myself into a pickle trying to squeeze two ListViews in the same activity. It works, using two separate ListFragments contained in a standard (vertical) LinearLayout.

The problem is, the two lists together are longer than the screen and the second list is therefore partially hidden. Visually, the user expects to drag the whole screen up and unveil the second list. But the two lists have their own internal scrolling and they do not allow for the whole screen to scroll as one piece.

Luckily the lists actually contain very few items (5 each on average). So, theoretically, I could populate a couple of LinearLayouts containers instead. The problem is, the data being displayed by the lists comes from a Cursor and is dynamic. While I am aware of the newView() and bindView() methods of the CursorAdapter, I don't quite understand how I can connect the adapter to the LinearLayout containers instead of ListViews. I.e. how does the CursorAdapter know that it must create 5 row items out of the 5 items it finds in its cursor? Where do I create the loop that iterates over the cursor item and creates the items in the LinearLayout container? And how do I refresh the content of the LinearLayout when the data in the Cursor changes? All the examples I'm finding neatly wrap these issues into the ListView provided by the ListActivity, but I can't use ListViews!

I'm confused!

Manu

**EDIT :** Here is the xml layout of the (Fragment)Activity when following breceivemail suggestion. Commented out is the original LinearLayout container, prior to breceivemail's suggestion. It should also be noted the the whole activity is in turn contained by a TabHost, but I don't know if that make any difference for the problem at hand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--              
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
-->

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
               android:textSize="36sp"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/SelectPlayer"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="@string/Playing"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:background="#999999"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.myDomain.myApp.PlayerListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/playing"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="@string/Reserve"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:background="#999999"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.myDomain.myApp.PlayerListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/reserve"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>      

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better solution to just create your layout, so the two ListViews fit the screen size?

Comment: It's a fair comment @KasperMoerch, but the height of the list items is unusually big by design. The list items need to be tapped on quickly, especially those in the first list, and it is a UI principle that the bigger something is the quicker it is to reach and interact with it.

Comment: This is all fair - but the general point of the ListView is that it's scrollable, meaning you can just scroll to the needed point in the list which also means that if you have two ListViews in one screen they only need to take up half the screen each. I get the impression that you're making some kind of game, which is cool. You shouldn't see this as criticism or me being stubborn - I'm simply trying to challenge your choice of UI-design. There might/might not be a better solution.

Comment: No worries @KasperMoerch, I am a little stuck on this issue and looking in different directions is useful so I wasn't seeing your comment as criticism nor did it crossed my mind you were being stubborn.

I'm not actually making a game but writing an app to take basketball statistics for my team/club (incidentally learning java+android in the process).

Comment: The first list is the list of players on the court (normally 5 but could _theoretically_ go down to 2) the second list is the players sitting as reserves, anywhere between 0 and 7. When something happens the user clicks on a player and is led to another Activity where he can select _what_ happened, i.e. a 2 points shot or a foul. Theoretically it might appear that only people actually playing can trigger an event, suggesting that only the on-the-court players list is necessary. In practice it might happen that a statistics about a person sitting as reserve needs to be incremented.

Comment: I.e. (extrme case) the person might swear at the referee from the bench and get a so-called Technical Foul (and even be expelled from the game). For this reason I'd like to keep the second list in the same view albeit normally less visible than the other. In this context, the large size (height) of the list items is due to the fast pace of the game: the quicker is an item to click on, the easier it is to log everything that happens.

Comment: Of course there other ways to have two lists. I could use two tabs or I could use ExpandableListViews. At this stage I'd prefer two consecutive (non-individually-scrolling) lists that can scroll as a single object. That's why I was asking how to bypass ListViews and populate a LinearLayout directly from a CursorAdapter.

Comment: If, however, no useful solution arises from this discussion/question I might indeed have to change tactic and make it easy to switch between the two lists rather than have them both onscreen at the same time. With my original UI design choice I might have problems anyway as eventually I'd like to drag&drop players from one list to the other and I'm not sure how easy it would be if the whole view can scroll vertically while I try the drag&drop in a similarly vertical motion.

Comment: What you could do then, is throw in a TabHost with two Tabs - one for 'On court' and one for 'Off court'. This way both ListViews can take up the whole screen (apart from the space the Tabs take up). A completely different approach would be getting your hands on a Tablet, which provides with so much more screen space. **EDIT** Hadn't seen your last two comments: If you believe the best solution is the one you mention, you should look into using something else than a Cursor or writing a wrapper for your Cursor that provides you with the needed implementation.

Comment: Yes, the use of two tabs is a possibility, but given that the activity we are dealing with is already in a tab, it would create a tabs-in-a-tab situation that I'd rather avoid. Having a tablet of course would open a whole new host of possibilities, but for now the target platforms are large screen mobiles: one thing at a time! Concerning the idea of wrapping a Cursor, well, that's part of what I was asking in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put your listViews in a vertical scroll. You can have scrollable listView inside of a vertical scroll by the following trick. use the following code and enjoy!

```
    private int listViewTouchAction;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...

        setListViewScrollable(myListView1);
        setListViewScrollable(myListView2);
    }

    private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
            list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
                    if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                    {
                        list.scrollBy(0, 1);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) {
                }

                @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    list.scrollBy(0, -1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

listViewTouchAction is a global integer value.

Comment: Dear @breceivemail, thanks for your effort. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The code is functional but together with the layout I added to the original post it only makes the two listview much shorter and they still retain their internal scrolling. No scrolling as a single view. Furthermore, every time I drag one list a little it shows less and less of the items views, eventually disappearing altogether, all items somehow hidden.

Question: when you write about the listViewTouchAction variable, do you mean Activity-global or Application-global?

Comment: I have tested it on Asus Eee, Gallagxy tab and all of emulators.